# Ruby on Rails SyntaxError using Strong Parms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to whitelist **mhealth_ids** in **/app/controllers/clients_controller.rb** as displayed below.

```
  def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :dob, :gender_id, :remove_image, :rh_options, :insurance_id, :state_id, :ed_id, :wk_id, :grade_id, :rsource_id, :image, :race_id, :employment_id, :comments, :email, :phone, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :name, rhealth_ids:[], :name, mhealth_ids:[])
end
```

I'm using the same syntax as **`:name, rhealth_ids:[]`** which works fine when **`:name, mhealth_ids:[]`**  isn't inserted.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm sure it's something small.

Comment: You should put exit in controller and check what actual value you get in params for :name, mhealth_ids:[]

Comment: @Vishal How would I write that?

Comment: just write exit in your client_params method or which ever method you call .than check params in console

Comment: @Vishal This is what is returned `SyntaxError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
..., :name, rhealth_ids:[], :name, mhealth_ids:[])
...                               ^):
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>`

Comment: @davis so its syntax error.. you have to solve this syntax error.. just see do you put any extra ',' or '.'.. in line 80 .clients_controller

Comment: Auto-hash-ified method arguments have to go together at the end of the argument list. You can't say `m(a, b: c, d)` you have to say `m(a, d, b: c)`. Your `rhealth_ids` and `mhealth_ids` have to go at the end or Ruby doesn't know what you're trying to say. Also, you've duplicated the `:name` in your `.permit`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. Your explanation was very helpful and I was able to correct my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for the original question.

```
 def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:firstName,  :lastName,:dob, :gender_id, :remove_image, :rh_options, :insurance_id, :state_id, :ed_id, :wk_id, :grade_id, :rsource_id, :image, :race_id, :employment_id, :comments, :email, :phone, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :name, rhealth_ids:[], mhealth_ids:[])
 end
```

Both **rhealth_ids** and **mhealth_ids** have to go at the end of Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays go at the end you copy pasted and forgot to take out the second :name.

Comment: But why do the arrays have to at the end?

Answer (score 0):

`:name` has been repeated erroneously. You need to remove the second `:name` before `mhealth_ids:[]`